# Android threads and battery life

Tags: java, android, multithreading, battery

If I have several threads running in my application, all of which have a while(true) loop with no Thread.sleep() in any of them to act as a ghetto action listener, would this negatively affect my battery life? By regular logic it should, however, I'm not sure whether the processor's constant monitoring of the while loops, would contribute a significant battery loss or not?

Comment: So I know this is a late comment on my question. But you should NEVER use a while(true) loop to check for a condition that may happen.
While(true) will use up that thread's cpu 100% and WILL drain the battery

Comment: If you use While(condition) with synchronisation's and lock's and wait() then it's better option. Never use infinite looper thread's as they use lot of system resources

Comment: What about while(true) but with Thread.sleep(`sometime`). `sometime` might equal 500 (milliseconds) at minimum, for example. Would this be fine? Or what's the minimum value that must be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down to what you do within the listeners/ while loop. If it involves stuff like wifi enabling sensors or CPU intensive tasks or network i/o  then its pretty obvious ,else you should do just fine.
Predominantly a few of the OS functions also do the same in the background.

However there seem to be better ways to handle stuff like this in android why not give those a try.

Comment: I saw a similar response to a similar question, but what constitutes "intensive"?
In my mind, having a while loops that does count++ seems intensive, or am I wrong?

Comment: From what your suggesting you seem to be doing fine as simple increments don't qualify for being intensive, however a few higher order calculations with BigInteger/BigDecimal can send your CPU for a toss(which I presume is not what your upto).More so as mentioned before Activating sensors,bitmap manipulations,encoding decoding videos etc if any are intensive.Hope you get a hang of it now.

Comment: @humblerookie do you have any reference to support this or explain in more detail? In regular Java, anything that does not invoke waiting for an interrupt (e.g. explicit waits, locks, synchronization, I/O) qualifies as "intensive", including a simple `count++` - because the CPU will just cycle in the loop as fast as it can.

Comment: Say I have a thread which updates a database in every second, will it drain the battery too much?